# C++ getline() doesn't end input

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

```
string str, temp;

string c;

cout << "Insert the character that ends the input:" << endl;

getline(cin, c);

cout << "Insert the string:" << endl;

getline(cin, str, c.c_str()[0]);
```

I should be able to put into the string "test" a string until I digit the ending char but if I enter a double new line it doesn't recognize the ending char and it doesn't end the input.

This is the output:

```
Insert the character that ends the input:
}
Insert the string:
asdf

}
do it}
damn}
```

Comment: your code and the example output is different. Can you post the correct one

Comment: Your code works for me. But I would use a straight `char` for `c`.

Comment: `c[0]` instead of `c.c_str()[0]` would've worked too, but I can't reproduce this behavior (g++-4.7, Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: I have LLVM and using `c[0]` doesn't work

Comment: @fpiro I assume you mean clang or llvm-gcc (llvm itself isn't a compiler). In either case, that should work just fine.

Comment: Works for me too using char c;

Comment: You mean that if you write my input it stops and proceed to the remaining part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to redesign your code a little bit, e.g. if the delimiter is a character, then why reading a `string` (and using a kind of obscure syntax like "`c.c_str()[0]`" - at least just use `c[0]` to extract the first character from the string)? Just read the single delimiter character.

Moreover, I see no unexpected results from `getline()`.

If you try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Insert the character that ends the input: " << endl;  
    char delim;
    cin >> delim;

    string str;   
    cout << "Insert the string: " << endl;   
    getline(cin, str, delim);

    cout << "String: " << str << endl;
}
```

the output is as expected, e.g. the input string "`hello!world`" is truncated at the delimiter "`!`" and the result is just "`hello`":

> ```
> C:\TEMP\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /MTd test.cpp
> test.cpp
>
> C:\TEMP\CppTests>test.exe
> Insert the character that ends the input:
> !
> Insert the string:
> hello!world
> String:
> hello
> ```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I discovered that the bug was in the algorithm which followed this input.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

> getline(cin, str, c[0]);

Comment: @Predheep - c is a char, it's not permissable to subscript a mere char type.